# endomorphism and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, invariance

Let $\phi: V \to V$ be an endomorphism over a $\mathbb{C}$-field. Show:

If there is a decomposition $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ with $V_1,V_2 \neq \{0\}$ and $\phi$-invariant,
then there exist $\phi$-invariant $U_1,U_2 \subset V$ with $\operatorname{dim} U_1 = \operatorname{dim} U_2 = 1$ and $U_1 \neq U_2$.

---

Since it's over $\mathbb{C}$ the minimal polynomial $\mu_\phi$ is product of linear factors (distinct?).

It is $v \in V_i \implies \phi(v) \in V_i$.

---

But I don't really see what to do..?

Answer (score 1):

Try to see what 1 dimensional invariant subspaces mean. And maybe make your statement stronger by requiring that $U_i \subset V_i$ which will automatically imply that $U_1 \neq U_2$.